# django submit form on change

Tags: python, django, forms, django-forms, submit

Hello I am trying to submit a form when selection an option on a `ChoiceField`

```
class ActionForm(forms.Form):
    """ Holds the options for mailbox management """
    choices = ['create new folder', 'delete', 'read', 'unread']
    action = forms.ChoiceField(choices=choices, attrs={'onchange': 'actionform.submit();'})
```

but now I get an invallid syntax when I try to load the form. I am pretty sure the `attrs={'onchange': 'actionform.submit();'})` is the problem, but not sure how else to do it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to set a [`widget`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/fields/#widget) argument on the field and pass [`attrs`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/widgets/#django.forms.Widget.attrs) argument:

```
action = forms.ChoiceField(choices=choices, 
                           widget=forms.Select(attrs={'onchange': 'actionform.submit();'}))
```

Also, the `choices` list should contain items containing two things inside:

```
choices = [(0, 'create new folder'), (1, 'delete'), (2, 'read'), (3, 'unread')]
```

Comment: thanks for the awnser. this seems to work, however now i think my choices is still wrong. i get the error: To many values to unpack

Answer (score 0):

In the template-html file’s form tag include the attribute

```
onchange="functionName()” to call:

function functionName(){
   var submitButton = 
document.getElementById(“the id of the button”);
   submitButton.click();
}
```

Give the submit button and id, for example:

```
input type="submit" value="Submit" id="myButton"
```

With CSS set the button’s visibility to:

```
#myButton{
   visibility: hidden;
}
```